# typescript how can I type a class property?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am implementing my version of Client side rendering and I want to type my `route` object.

its structure is as follows:

```js
import Post from './Post'

export const route = {
    path: '/post',
    component: Post
}
```

Note that Post is a custom class that is not instantiated.

There will be multiple components but all components will be inheriting a class called `BaseComponent`. Is there a way to type `route.component` using its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `typeof {ClassName}`

```js
type Route = {
 path: string,
 component: typeof BaseComponsnet
}
```

Please keep in mind that you can use `BaseComponent` and `typeof BaseComponent`. First one represents class instance, the second one represents class type itself

Comment: that why it showed as an error when I tried `BaseComponent`. Thanks!

Comment: @JunsooChoi, here https://catchts.com/oop-style , in my blog, you can find more examples of class typings

Comment: captain-yossarian Thanks :)